# Run sudo mysql -e "SET ***'rootpassword')" ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) on Github Actions

Tags: mysql, linux, github, github-actions, root

I ran the command `sudo mysql -e "SET Password=PASSWORD('rootpassword')"`
but it was showing the error

.[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql -e "SET PASSWORD = 'YourChosenPassword';"
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Comment: This is just syntax issue there is no philosophy or explanation behind it

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)